# Highlight vertices by vertex color as animation

Tags: animation, vertices, color

I have a mesh object with specific data information displayed by various vertex colors. In my case, each color value represents a specific time point from red (earliest) to blue (latest). Now, I would like to make an animation in a way that all vertices with the same color data light up at the same time.

So basically there are three parts of the problem:

1. Select all vertices with the same color
2. Adjust the hightlighting only to these vertices and at the same time if possible
3. Store the highlighting as keyframe for animation

-> Repeat for the next color value

Hope anyone can help.

This is an example of how the object looks
[image]

Comment: didn't you ask that same question a few days before!?

Comment: Yes on a different page, but my problem wasn't solved. Thats why I tried it here again, hope thats okay.

Answer (score 0):

This can be effected by using the hue component of the vertex color. For future reference, I might use black to white and gone with the value component instead, as you’d have more dynamic range. In this case, you’ll also have to use a Map Range mode to stretch the hue of blue all the way to 1 (I think blue’s hue is 0.66, so use that as the From Max value). Now, use a Math node on the gradient value, set to Compare. Animate the value it’s comparing to so that it moves across the 0-1 range in whichever direction you want, and set the compare threshold based on how wide you want the illumination band to be. Plug the output into emission strength, and there you go.

Comment: Thanks for the specific answer, I'll try that. One follow up question, is it possible to store / export that animation as glb file? Or do I need to bake the highlighting in every keyfame somehow?

Comment: @hans1 I’m not sure.

Comment: Okay thanks @TheLabCat